# Tokens stick when splitting a String in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split a test String, "1 + 2 = 3 += 4 + --5" into its components without relying on spaces. I want the end result to be { 1, +, 2, =, 3, +=, 4, +, --, 5 } however some tokens seem to stick together. I wrote the following Regex to split the String:

```
"(?<=(\\.)|(\\w))\\s*(?=[O])|(?<=[O])\\s*(?=(\\.)|(\\w))"
```

and then used the ReplaceAll function to replace "O" with the following, which are my operators that I want to split on:

```
"(\\\\+)|(\\\\=)|(\\\\+=)|(\\\\-)"
```

However when applying this regex to splitting the String I provided as an example, I get the following result: { 1, +, 2, =, 3, +=, 4, +--, 5 }. Why do the minuses stick to the plus in the 2nd to last token? Is there anyway to fix this and make the split tokens appear as { 1, +, 2, =, 3, +=, 4, +, --, 5 }?

Comment: I'd urge against parsing with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do matching instead of splitting.

```
String a = "1 + 2 = 3 += 4 +--5";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+|[^\\w\\s]+").matcher(a);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, +, 2, =, 3, +=, 4, +--, 5]
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in my code. But this doesn't seem to work if the input string is "1 + 2 = 3 += 4 +--5". Is there a regex that does not rely on spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String input = "1 + 2 = 3 += 4 + --5";
//StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, "1234567890", true);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[");

while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
  //builder.append(stringTokenizer.nextElement());
  builder.append(stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString().trim());
  builder.append(stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ? "," : "]");
}
System.out.printf("Using the java.util.StringTokenizer: %s%n", builder);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Using the java.util.StringTokenizer: [1, +, 2, =, 3, +=, 4, +, --5]
```

Comment: This works but it relies on spaces... Any way without spaces?

Comment: Use all the numbers as `delim` and pass `true` as `returnDelims`. That will make the trick also; you can have spaces or not